# Setting up bootstrap 4 environment with npm and css code not working in chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, npm, unicode, sass

[image]I am following a tutorial to set up my bootstrap 4 environment by using node package management and sass. I installed bootstrap using `npm install bootstrap` command and then import the source code to a `main.scss` file using the `@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"`. I then installed Ruby and SASS with `gem install sass`, so it enables me to run sass `main.scss main.css` to convert boostrap file to a css file that can be link to the html file.

However, the boostrap code only works in IE but no Google Chrome. I inspected the code in google chrome and it seems it is reading the code all right, but don't know why bootstrap is not working in this case as you can see the form is not styled at all. so confused now.

I searched for what cause the problem and found out that there is someone's answer that might be relevant to my problem:

> IE and Edge are not fussy : stylesheets are rendered regardless of
>   the encodings. But Chrome is totally intolerant of unmatched
>   encodings.

How can I change the unicode for my css file when it is generated by sass in the background? In addition, how to change the code to meet the same standard as my html file? is this unicode related issue??

[image]

I guess there is no point to show the code since `main.css` was created by sass for Bootstrap 4. I am not sure if someone has experienced a similar situation and know what I am talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing node-sass (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass), and also install "npm install bootstrap" and import it as 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' which will import bootstrap4 (latest)